# Responsive table height Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, react-bootstrap

How can I make table height to be responsive when displayed inside row element? In this row element there are two tables and an image, so that row height is set to fit this image. Or maybe there is another way to make labels for image with fixed size? I just found the way to set table height using something like `{ height: 120%; }`, but its not responsive.

Code:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-8">
    <div className="col-md-2">
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="text-center vert-align">Table1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table1Content}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-5">
      <img className="img-responsive" src={"data:image/jpg;base64," + this.state.image.image} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-2">
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="text-center vert-align">Table2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table2Content}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. Could you provide an example or a JS.Fiddle? By default a table cell will expand to the largest element in a row (unless the content inside is absolute positioned)

Comment: @crazymatt hey thanks for reply, I just created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6eq89r4r/) with my situation. As you can see there are two tables on the sides of the image, so I just want to stretch them to image size(table row height should be dynamic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `display: flex;` and also set height for `.table` and `.table-responsive`.

Add `row-eq-height` to your row, and remove an old class `col-md-8`, if you want use `col-*-x`, please add more `row` div outside, because it can be wrong with `float` attribute of `col-*-x`.

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.table {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-responsive {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Check result here: https://jsfiddle.net/6eq89r4r/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but table is still smaller than image, it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Updated, please take a look on link `jsfiddle` link above.